# Python: faster function for kernel evaluation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I've got a function like below that evaluates a kernel between the instances x and y:

```
def my_hik(x, y):
     """Histogram-Intersection-Kernel """
     summe = 0
     for i in xrange(len(x)):
         summe += min(x[i],y[i])
     return summe
     #return np.sum(np.min(np.array([[x],[y]]),0))

metrics.pairwise.pairwise_kernels(instances, metric=my_hik, n_jobs=-1)
```

I call it with sklearns pairwise_kernels-function. But my data (some 3000 instances with a hundred attributes) seems to be too large and the calculation for one matrix takes minutes (as the function is called 9*10^6 times). Is there a way to make the function run faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def fast_hik(x, y):
    return np.minimum(x, y).sum()
```

Timings:

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(100)
>>> y = np.random.randn(100)
>>> %timeit my_hik(x, y)
10000 loops, best of 3: 50.3 µs per loop
>>> %timeit fast_hik(x, y)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.55 µs per loop
```

Greater speedups are obtained for longer vectors:

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(1000)
>>> y = np.random.randn(1000)
>>> %timeit my_hik(x, y)
1000 loops, best of 3: 498 µs per loop
>>> %timeit fast_hik(x, y)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.92 µs per loop
```

Comment: I consider myself thoroughly trounced!

Comment: FYI, should you ever have 100x as many points, have a look at this: http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00006964/01/vedaldi10.pdf or just use the AdditiveChi2Sampler. I often find that works better than histogram intersection.